# Code First Model Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a similar structure like below.

```
public class Price
{
   public decimal Amount {get; set;}
   public string Currency {get; set;}
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Price Price {get; set;}
}
```

I want a Product table in database that will apart Price to its properties. For instance;

```
**ProductTable**
--Id
--Name
--Amount
--Currency
```

Then when I get a product from database, it will automatically bind **Amount** and **Currency** to **Price** object of the **Product**. How should I make this structure by using Entity Framework Code First ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Price property have to be virtual, and it should work:

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual Price Price {get; set;}
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can specify custom column name by override `OnModelCreating` method in your `DbContext` class:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(u => u.Price.Amount)
                                       .HasColumnName("Amount");
 }
```

Comment: _If_ lazy loading is enabled, which it is by default.

Answer (score 2):

answer given by @Miłosz Wierzbicki will create a seperate table for `Price`

but in your case i dont think you need a seprate table for that
so defining the Price as Complex type would same it inside the same Table with "Price" appended to database field names and will also automatically map the names when retriving or saving data

```
[ComplexType]
public class Price
{
   public decimal Amount {get; set;}
   public string Currency {get; set;}
}
```

Read more about [[ComplexType]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382831.aspx)

Comment: Not really. It will create columns Price_Amount and Price_Currency because Price object don't have primary key.

Comment: thats what im saying here in my ans